# Logical loop confusion javascript

Tags: javascript, while-loop, addeventlistener

I have an array of songs, where each song has its index number in the array and the .source property. I wrote a script that creates a table row for each song:

```
var list = document.getElementsByClassName("preview")[1];
for (y = 0; y < allSongs.length; y ++) {
    var row = list.insertRow(-1);
    var celeft = row.insertCell(0);
    var celright = row.insertCell(1);
    celright.innerHTML = allSongs[y].name;
    celeft.setAttribute("class", "left");
```

But now I want to make all those left cells (0) linked to the songs, which I tried to do this way:

```
    x = document.getElementsByClassName("left");
var counter = 0;
while (counter < allSongs.length) {
    x[counter+1].addEventListener('click', function() {
        document.getElementById("audplayer").setAttribute("src", allSongs[counter].source);
    });
    counter++;
}
```

Basically, I made them clickable with the addEventListener property, but the problem is that the **addEventListener function is not excecuted with the loop, so the counter value is not saved, and everytime I click one of the table cells, counter has a value of 3 at that moment.** I understand where the problem comes from but I cannot solve it. How can this be solved?

*More details (if the explanation wasnt clear enough):
I want each of the table cells to perform a different action (play different songs), but they all play the same one - allSongs[3], because counter value is taken when the click event happens, not every time the while loop is executed.*

Comment: Nope, you only have **one single** element, the second one, that's what `[1]` does

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your loops with map and _.zip from lodash.

Example pseudocode:

```
song_and_elem_pairs = _.zip(allSongs, x);
song_and_elem_pairs.map(function (song, elem) {
    elem.addEventListener('click', function() {
        document.getElementById("audplayer").setAttribute("src", 
            song.source);
    }
});
```

You can also similarly replace the `for (y = 0; y < allSongs.length; y ++)` loop with a map.

This is certainly not the only way to do this, but it's how I would approach it and I think it should fix your problem.

Comment: The foreach strategy in the link Yury posted above might be simpler if you're more familiar with loop comprehensions than higher order functions.